# problem to construct a class, construct with other classes object [uml designer]

Tags: eclipse, uml, uml-designer

I failed to represent, in a class diagram, a class construct by 2 object from 2 others classes(a constructor with two parameters, where the parameter types are two other classes).
I create my first class (A) empty then the second (B) empty too. Then I add a property to the first but I can't use B.

The tool is UML designer (for eclipse). My step are:

- creation of empty Class A
- creation of empty Class B
- creation of empty Class C and fail to "fill" Class A with 2 objects, instances of Class B and c.

!(https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9Xbu.jpg)

Comment: Please try to improve the text. In the title, you wrote: "problem to construct a class construct...". What is a "class construct". Do you mean a class constructor? Then, you wrote: "a class construct by 2 object from 2 others classes". Do you mean a constructor with two parameters, where the parameter types are two other classes? It would help if you would draw manually (or in Paint or whatever) what you want to achieve and then add the picture to your question.

Comment: I see you have added a picture. It shows two attributes b and c. These are not constructors, but regular attributes.

Answer (score 0):

To create an property b of type B in class A in UML Designer, create a new property for class A and type

```
b : B
```

UML Designer will automatically look for a class called B.

See https://www.umldesigner.org/ref-doc/implement-the-application.html#manage-features.